Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: RemoteTestNG has been compiled by Java Runtime version 55.0,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/remote/RemoteTestNG has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

You're trying to run the tests with Java 8 (class version 52), but the TestNG jar you're using was built with Java 11 (class version 55). Replace your runtime with Java 11 or newer, and you should be fine.

Its worked after changing to java 11, Thank you
